# Trouble Seeding

Tags: linux, debian, bittorrent, transmission

I'm trying to distribute some large video files from a recent talk I helped organize, and figured putting torrents up for the HD versions would be a good approach.

I've used [these instructions](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/06/08/how-to-create-and-seed-a-torrent-in-ubuntu-using-transmission-command-line/) (modified slightly because I'm not running Ubutntu, and also because [openbittorrent.org](http://openbittorrent.com/) suggests using the tracker url `udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce` instead of what the article specifies) to set up `transmission-daemon`. Everything seems to work; I've got the appropriate entries in `settings.json` and the newly created `.torrent`s are being added by the daemon, but when I try to start up `transmission-cli` to actually seed them, it gives me a giant column of

`Tracker gave an error:: Connection failed`

Needless to say, trying to download the same torrent from one of my other machines gets me 0 peers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the tracker is actually valid?  Why don't you just use your own tracker?

Comment: @Ramhound - How would I go about verifying that openbittorrent.org provides a valid tracker? The only reason I didn't set up my own is that I've never done so; are there docs for doing it on Debian?

Comment: Use some other tracker as a test. If it starts working you know the openbittorrent.org tracker is dead.  As for setting up your own tracker, how you do that, is well documented.

Comment: @Ramhound - Adding `udp://tracker.publicbt.com:80/announce` to the list of trackers seems to get it working (I did also have to switch clients to `rtorrent`). RE: Tracker documentation, that seems to be false. I can find plenty on [setting up seedboxes](http://www.debianuserforums.org/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=583), and some on [how to build a tracker from source](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/opentracker/), but nothing on how to configure one or how to check it's working properly. There's [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=574400), but all useful looking links there lead to 404s.

Comment: The first setup to configure your own tracker would be to build said software.  Of course it doesn't really matter.  You have proven the tracker you wanted to use wasn't working by using a different tracker.